# Fit the site in iframe

Tags: html, iframe

I have the following HTML code in which the images can move.

```
<div id="templatemo_slider">
<!-- This is the container for the carousel. -->
    <div id = "carousel1" style="width:960px; height:280px;background:none;overflow:scroll; margin-top: 20px">            
<!-- All images with class of "cloudcarousel" will be turned into carousel items -->
<!-- You can place links around these images -->
        <a href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/1" rel="lightbox"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/slider/02.jpg" alt="CSS Templates 2" title="Website Templates 2" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/2" rel="lightbox"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/slider/02.jpg" alt="CSS Templates 2" title="Website Templates 2" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/3" rel="lightbox"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/slider/03.jpg" alt="CSS Templates 3" title="Website Templates 3" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.templatemo.com/page/4" rel="lightbox"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/slider/04.jpg" alt="CSS Templates 4" title="Website Templates 4" /></a>
        <a href="http://www.flashmo.com/page/1" rel="lightbox"><img class="cloudcarousel" src="images/slider/05.jpg" alt="Flash Templates 1" title="Flash Templates 1" /></a>
    </div>

<!-- Define left and right buttons. -->
    <center>
        <input id="slider-left-but" type="button" value="" />
        <input id="slider-right-but" type="button" value="" />
    </center>
</div>
```

For screenshot link actual :

[image]

I want to put webpages instead of images.

For that I have tried using

```
<iframe class="cloudcarousel" src="http://www.bookmyshow.com" width = "800px" height ="1000px"></iframe></a>
```

It shows the image, but is not properly aligned, after putting width in iframe the frame is moving to left and inside the page bookmyshow is coming incomplete"

Screenshot Link error:

[image]

Comment: Looks like a problem with the display property (block vs. inline-block) or the position property (relative vs. absolute). Would need a demo to be sure.

Comment: iframe is exactly the same inline element as img and shold be displayed in same way.  (And width = "800px" px is not nessessary)

Comment: if i will not define width then page will not be visible...

Comment: @Surya Gupta: I mean, 'px' is not nessesary.